# Execute PowerShell script in another context

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, script

My powershell script contain a 'set-location' (cd) command. After running the script, my current directory is changed, but I don't want it that way.

**test.ps1**:

```
cd d:\temp (new line)
myProgram (new line)
(eof)
```

Those 'new line', 'eof' are markings only.

PowerShell console:

```
PS D:\projects\abc> .\test.ps1
This line is the output of myProgram
PS D:\temp> _
```

I need my PowerShell console stay in **d:\projects\abc** instead of being at **d:\temp** after running the script. Any quick solution?

I can not just run **d:\temp\myProgram** because myProgram is only working in that d:\temp directory. And also, I can't put "cd d:\projects\abc" after executing myProgram in test.ps1 as myProgram is a web server which I have to terminate when I want using Ctrl+C.

Comment: `pushd d:\temp; myProgram; popd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by PetSerAl in the comment under question:

```
pushd d:\temp
myProgram
popd
```

I found another solution too

```
PS D:\projects\abc> powershell .\test.ps1
```